# Azure data factory dataflow dynamic / schemadrift input create derived column using a known named column from the incoming dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to create a statically named derived column using a column value of the row from schema drift/dynamic input dataset in Azure data factory dataflow?
We can use column pattern matching but it doesn't seem to let us use a static named derived column.
We need this derived column name to be able to use in the next Alter Row to decide if delete/upsert to be made.

[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple columns named `ELTSysChangeOperation` in input? Why cannot you just create new derived column `String_ELTSysChangeOperation` == `toString(ELTSysChangeOperation)`.[Derived_column_settings](https://i.imgur.com/n7WLLEl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Derived column transformation**, you can create a new column or you can update the existing field. To add a new column in the derived column transformation,

1. Type the new column name in the column text box.
2. Give the value for that column in the expression text box.

[image]

This will create the static new column name which can be used for further transformations.

Refer, [MS document on Derived column transformation in mapping data flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column)